# BigQuery Java API - QueryReponse.getSchema() gives null

Tags: java, google-bigquery

We use Java API for accessing BigQuery. At present we experience a lot of query failures when `QueryResponse` object has `null` schema info in it. Typically rerun of the same query passes. Questions:

- [Javadoc](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/QueryResponse.html#getSchema%28%29) says `null` is a sign of unsuccessful query. Why in this particular case BigQuery is not throwing `GoogleJsonResponseException` as it usually does in other cases to report error?
- Our read queries are very simple and table contains ~5m records why do we experience a lot of such faults? What is the reason for them? BQ bugs? Unavailability periods?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

It may just be that the job is not yet done. Check the getJobComplete() field to make sure the query job has completed. If it hasn't, use `getQueryResults()` to retry. You might also try increasing the timeout of the original query by calling `setTimeoutMs()` in the query request.

Comment: You suggest that this synchronous Java API returns a response but the underlying query may not be finished yet and we still must check the status? (we have set timeouts to be 35 secs)